# CSV file encoding in Rails with S3 and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, amazon-s3, character-encoding

My rails app uploads CSV files to S3, then subsequently pulls them down into a tempfile to send each row's data to a Sidekiq worker. I'm using Carrierwave and fog to handle the uploading.

This all worked beautifully until recently switching to Heroku, and now, when trying to create my tempfile I get the following error:

```
Error type Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
Error message "\xA2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I've tried setting the encoding when creating the tempfile as well as working with the CSV file and continue to get the same error. I cannot reproduce this error on my local machine, which has made this entire process that much more fun :)

Currently, my Sidekiq worker calls the following method:

```
def upload_csv(filename, file_path)
  file = Tempfile.new(filename, Rails.root.join('tmp'), encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8").tap do |f|
   open(file_path).rewind
   f.write(open(file_path).read)
   f.close
  end

  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true, encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8")do |row|
   #do stuff to rows
  end
end
```

I understand the very basics of encoding, but I'm super stuck on this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that after setting the encoding on the tempfile, its charset still comes back as `us-ascii` not sure if that makes a difference....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but I found a solution that works for me:

```
def upload_csv(filename, file_path)
  file = Tempfile.new(filename, Rails.root.join('tmp')).tap do |f|
   open(file_path).rewind
   f.write(open(file_path).read.force_encoding('utf-8'))
   f.close
  end

  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true)do |row|
   #do stuff to rows
  end
end
```

Even though I could confirm that the file was `UTF-8` encoded before it was uploaded, `open(@file_path).read.encoding` returning an `ASCII-8BIT` encoding. It was getting confused on how to write the file and convert it from `ASCII-8BIT` to `UTF-8`.